# How to discard subsequent rows of an ID, after a threshold value of a different column is found?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need a fast way (preferably using index operations), to achieve this. See the first dataframe below.

```
  ID  trn_amt  month_of_trn  gap
0  A      100             0  0.0
1  A      140             3  3.0
2  A      210             9  6.0
3  A      320            10  1.0
4  A      580            13  3.0
5  B      101             0  0.0
6  B      120             2  2.0
7  B      300             8  6.0
8  B      200            10  2.0
```

I have a threshold value for the variable `gap` (which shows the gap in consecutive transactions of a customer), say 5, such that after encountering that value in the column `gap`, I want to drop all subsequent transaction rows for the customer ID in question. The resultant dataframe should look like below:

[image]

I have millions of rows in the dataframe. So looping will obviously not work. Please suggest a better way.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Kindly don't downvote just for this reason. First of all, the image is not of any code, but the output. So your point is not valid.

Comment: Apologies. I thought it was you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First compare by `invert` condition by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) for `>=` by treshold and get cumulative sum per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html), last compare by `0` for geenral solution if multiple values greater by treshold in data:

```
N = 5
df1 = df[df['gap'].ge(N).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().eq(0)]
print (df1)
  ID  trn_amt  month_of_trn  gap
0  A      100             0  0.0
1  A      140             3  3.0
5  B      101             0  0.0
6  B      120             2  2.0
```

Comment: What if I have to get the complement of this. i.e. only the rows which have to be discarded?

Comment: @RodrikTheReader - then invert mask by `df1 = df[~df['gap'].ge(N).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().eq(0)]` or use `ne` for not equal like `df[df['gap'].ge(N).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().ne(0)]`

Comment: you're awesome. Bless you.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work, where `thres` is the threshold value.

```
import numpy as np

df = df[df['gap'].lt(thres).groupby(df['ID']).apply(np.logical_and.accumulate)]
```